# How can make script run?

Tags: perl

I make below script But script running result has error
"Use of uninitialized value $bay_name in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 92."

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;
use Getopt::Long;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;


## perl time variable
my $dt = strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S',localtime);


## Variable reset
my ($key, $value, $bay_name, $dot) = '';
$dot = ' ';

for (`cat test | awk 'NF' | awk /:/ | sed -e 's/  \+/ /g' -e 's/ : /:/g' | egrep "All|Bay|Number"`)
    {
        ($key, $value) = m/(.*?):(.*?)$/g
            or next;

        if ($key eq 'BayName') {
            $bay_name = $value;
        }
        else {
            $key = $bay_name . $dot . $key;
        }

        if ($key eq 'BayName') {
            undef $key;
        }
        else {
        print "\t,\n";
        print "\t{\n";
        print "\t\t\"{#HWNAMES}\":\"$key\",\n";
        print "\t\t\"{#HWSTATUS}\":\"$value\"\n";
        print "\t}\n";
    }
    }
```

I want Fix it

test file has below content

```
System Bay

  Bay Name                             :    SB-1
  Number of Standby Power Supplies     :    4
  Number of Drive Enclosures           :    0
  Number of Enclosure Slots            :    2
  Number of MIBE Enclosures            :    2

  Summary Status of Contained Modules
    All Standby Power Supplies         :    Normal
    All Enclosures                     :    Normal
    All Link Control Cards             :    Normal
    All Power Supplies                 :    Normal
    All Enclosure Slots                :    Normal
    All Power Supplies                 :    Normal
    All Fans                           :    Normal
    All Management Modules             :    Normal
    All IO Module Carriers             :    Normal
    All Directors                      :    Normal
    All MIBE Enclosures                :    Normal
    All Power Supplies                 :    Normal

Drive Bays

  Bay Name                             :    DB-1A
  Number of Standby Power Supplies     :    8
  Number of Drive Enclosures           :    16

  Summary Status of Contained Modules
    All Enclosures                     :    Normal
    All Link Control Cards             :    Normal
    All Power Supplies                 :    Normal
    All Standby Power Supplies         :    Normal
```

I want below result
Bay Name row is delete in out put
all content change blow format

```
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Standby Power Supplies",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Enclosures",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Link Control Cards",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Power Supplies",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Enclosure Slots",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Power Supplies",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Fans",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Management Modules",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All IO Module Carriers",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Directors",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All MIBE Enclosures",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    },
    {
            "{#HWNAMES}":"SB-1 All Power Supplies",
            "{#HWSTATUS}":"Normal"
    }
```

Below is my script

```
for (`/opt/emc/SYMCLI/bin/symcfg -sid $sid list -env_data`) {

        if (/^\s+Bay Name\s+:\s+(\S+)$/){
                $bay_name = $1;

        } elsif (/(Number.*)\s+:\s+(\d+)/){
                print "\t{\n";
                print "\t\t\"{#HWNAMEC}\":\"$bay_name $1\",\n";
                print "\t\t\"{#HWCOUNT}\":\"$2\"\n";
                print "\t},\n";


        } elsif (/(All.*)\s+:\s+(\S+)/) {
                print "\t{\n";
                print "\t\t\"{#HWNAMES}\":\"$bay_name $1\",\n";
                print "\t\t\"{#HWSTATUS}\":\"$2\"\n";
                print "\t},\n";
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe remove the `tail -n +5 | head -n -1` part to actually process the rest of your file...

Comment: your code metnions "BayName" but theoutput of your cat is "Bay Name" so you never actually set the bay variable since you never match it. you should use data dumper to check your variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without using all the shell pipes and functions you could achieve this with a little bit of perl on its own.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bay_name;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp();
    if (/^\s+Bay Name\s+:\s+(\S+)$/){
        $bay_name = $1;
    } elsif (/(Number of Standby Power Supplies)\s+:\s+(\d+)/){
        print "$bay_name $1 : $2\n";
    } elsif (/(All Standby Power Supplies|All Enclosures)\s+:\s+(\S+)/) {
        print "$bay_name $1 : $2\n";
    }
}


__DATA__
System Bay

  Bay Name                             :    SB-1
  Number of Standby Power Supplies     :    4

  Summary Status of Contained Modules
    All Standby Power Supplies         :    Normal

Drive Bays

  Bay Name                             :    DB-1A
  Number of Standby Power Supplies     :    8

  Summary Status of Contained Modules
    All Enclosures                     :    Normal
```

This produces the following output based on your example data

```
SB-1 Number of Standby Power Supplies : 4
SB-1 All Standby Power Supplies : Normal
DB-1A Number of Standby Power Supplies : 8
DB-1A All Enclosures : Normal
```

Comment: Thank. I want change elseif include "All" content and "Number". How can make?

Comment: `elsif (/(Number)\s+:\s+(\d+)/){
        print "$bay_name $1 : $2\n";
    } elsif (/(All)\s+:\s+(\S+)/) {
        print "$bay_name $1 : $2\n";
    }`

Comment: you would need to use `elsif (/(Number.*)\s+:\s+(\d+)/){` and `elsif (/(All.*)\s+:\s+(\S+)/) {` that will match lines which contain All and Number. However, i am not sure why you would want to do that, unless your file contains other lines you have not shown that you are also trying to capture.

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand what you are asking.

Comment: I change quistion. for your understanding

Answer (score 1):

The actual question you asked is fixed by adding

```
my $bay_name;
```

inside your `for` loop. You've got `use strict` turned on, which is good practice and requires declaration of variables, but no declaration of `$bay_name`, which is what the error message refers to.

However, others have pointed out that calling a pipeline from Perl is entirely unnecessary and you can improve the code in various other ways.